ERROR: Failed building wheel for kiwisolver / command 'cl.exe' failed: None
I am trying to pip install a software called Virtual Scanner.
I try pip install virtual-scanner as recommended in their website and get the following error always at the same point of the installation:
Building wheels for collected packages: kiwisolver
  Building wheel for kiwisolver (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [10 lines of output]
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_ext
      building 'kiwisolver' extension
      creating build
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-312
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-312\Release
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-312\Release\py
      cl.exe /c /nologo /O2 /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -I. -IC:\Users\yuria\anaconda3\include -IC:\Users\yuria\anaconda3\Include -I\targets\x64 -I\targets\x64 /EHsc /Tppy/constraint.cpp /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-cpython-312\Release\py/constraint.obj /EHsc
      error: command 'cl.exe' failed: None
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for kiwisolver
  Running setup.py clean for kiwisolver
Failed to build kiwisolver
ERROR: ERROR: Failed to build installable wheels for some pyproject.toml based projects (kiwisolver)

using:
Windows 11, Python 3.12.4, Anaconda Prompt
Does someone have any ideia of how to fix that?
I already have kiwisolver installed, and trying to apply fixes from other posts, I also installed cmake and updated pip.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
